# How to get base url in my custom.js

Tags: magento-1.9

How to get base URL in my custom Java script  file i have to call my controller its working for static URL i want to get dynamic base URL how to get it in Java script file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get the base url via javscript

```
var mainUrl = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + "/";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get below ways

```
console.log(location.hostname);
console.log(document.domain);
alert(window.location.hostname)

console.log("document.URL : "+document.URL);
console.log("document.location.href : "+document.location.href);
console.log("document.location.origin : "+document.location.origin);
console.log("document.location.hostname : "+document.location.hostname);
console.log("document.location.host : "+document.location.host);
console.log("document.location.pathname : "+document.location.pathname);
```

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

1) Go to : `js/custom/custom.js` and create your file: `custom.js` and add this:

```
/*FUNCTION*/
<?php $baseUrl = $this->getBaseUrl() ; ?>
    function getBaseUrl() {
    return '<?php echo $baseUrl; ?>'; 
} 

/*VAR*/
var BASE_URL = '<?php echo  Mage::getBaseUrl(); ?>';
```

2) Go to : `app/design/frontend/{package}/{theme}/layout/local.xml`

and add this:

```
<default>
...
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="addItem"><type>js</type><name>custom/custom.js</name></action>
    </reference>
...
</default>
```